# Duplicate keys in custom configuration section - will the last always be chosen?

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

If I define a custom section in my App.config file, and add duplicate keys, for example:

```
<myCustomSection>
    <add key="Foobar" value="AppConfig,FirstValue" />
    <add key="Foobar" value="AppConfig,SecondValue" />        
</myCustomSection
```

The last value ('SecondValue' in this case) is chosen, at least on .NET 4. However, is this behaviour likely to be consistent across different versions of the .NET Framework? How about Mono?